# How can i access the array of object from the object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have json response from the backend its returning object so i am having problem accessing object inside object, so in below case I want to access the  `dataUploadLengthValidationDTOs`.`Var` response is returning the object but How can i access the data for `dataUploadLengthValidationDTOs`.

json.js

```
batchFileTypeKey: 3383
commentText: null
controlcount: null
createdUserText: null
currentInventoryControlcount: null
currentInventoryProcessCount: null
currentInventoryRiskCount: null
dataFile: null
dataLoadBatchKey: 2901
dataUploadLengthValidationDTOs: Array[2]
filename: "process_search_all_success_2.xlsx"
identifier: null
importSuccessFlag: true
lengthValidationError: true
loadSuccessFlag: false
originatingSrcSystemLkupCode: null
parentId: null
processCount: null
recordCount: 2
riskCount: null
templateType: "PRC Inventory"
templateTypeCode: "RA_PRC_INVNT_LOAD_FI"
userInitiatedImportFlag: false
validationMessage: "Failure"
validationSuccessFlag: false
```

mainctrl.js

```
var response = e.response;
console.log(response,'...recieved data from server');
console.log(response)
```

Comment: `response.dataUploadLengthValidationDTOs[0]`

Comment: i am getting an error Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Then your `response` doesn't contain the property `dataUploadLengthValidationDTOs` - what does your `console.log` output?

Comment: response does have property 'dataUploadLengthValidationDTOs' as i pasted in question

Comment: I dont know why its throwing response.dataUploadLengthValidationDTOs undefined

Comment: Is `response` an array?

Comment: response is object and dataUploadLengthValidationDTOs is an array

Comment: Try `response.dataUploadLengthValidationDTOs` and check what you get.

Comment: response[0].dataUploadLengthValidationDTOs solves the problem thanks for the help guys